# No action responded to search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, routes, action

i have defined a method called 'search' in my RecipesController which is not private. in routes.rb i have the following:

```
  map.connect 'recipes/search', :controller => :recipes, :action => :search
```

i get the following error:

> No action responded to search.
>   Actions: ...

where my method 'search' does not appear in the actions list. if i change the method name from 'search' to 'searchthings' and the action in routes to 'searchthings' then this seems to work. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

cancel that. i had the method defined already as private and accepting one argument.